# Detecting a mobile device by a specific identifier? JavaScript, jQuery, JQuery Mobile, MAC AirWatch

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, jquery-mobile

Before you mark this as a duplicate question, please read the entire question.

I've built a jQuery Mobile application that I'm trying to make as secure as possible. I'd like to limit the usage to specific iPad devices, without traditional authentication. I'm using HTML5, jQuery, jQuery Mobile and MAC's AirWatch for added security.

First, I know there are ways of identifying if an HTML5 'browser/navigator' type is mobile using navigator.userAgent.

```
var is_mobile = ( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) ? true : false;
```

Or, more specifically, if it's an iPad.

```
var is_ipad = ( /iPad/.test(navigator.userAgent) ) ? true : false;
```

But, now imagine your company has 100 iPads out in the world, using this app. Does anyone know of a good javascript based way to identify specifically what iPad is using the jQuery Mobile application?

I thought about setting a custom identifier in HTML5 Local Storage, but that would require visiting each iPad to setup a custom local storage value. This would be difficult as the iPads are not all accessible by myself.

Does anyone know if MAC's AirWatch program has the potential of setting the initial Local Storage for one of it's Apps on the Desktop? Please feel free to throw out other ideas.

Comment: Are you talking about HTML5's local storage? if so you don't need to do any prep work on the device, just generate your GUID server side and store it on the device.

Comment: On a side note it should be mentioned that sniffing the user agent will get you which devices are an iPad however this is by no means **secure** since anyone that wants to can spoof their user agent.

Comment: Yes, HTML5 local storage. I assume a GUID would be a good way to mark the iPads, but I'll have to do it programmically thru JavaScript and reference an iPads table in a database.

Comment: Are you hoping to tie something very specific to a device? e.g. the MAC address that very uniquely identifies the device? Or do you just want to be able to tell that have X number of unique devices accessing your app (but you don't care or need to know which user is using which)?

Comment: I'd prefer to "identify specifically" the device in use.

Comment: I think you might be stuck to get a really good identifier with JavaScript (/web technologies) alone. What you really want is the MAC address (or an equivalent GUID that you can match to the device.  Shy of telling the user (or the person setting it up) to go to: **Settings** > **General** > **About** > **Wi-Fi Address** (e.g. 00:26:00:82:C6:02) and enter that value in a form... I think you're going to need an MDM tool, and or a wrapper technology like Cordova/PhoneGap.  Even then I'm not sure if they will be able to "pass" that info to your web app. :-(